# Gnome control center not opening from command line as root user

Tags: command-line, gnome, gtk, gnome-control-center

I am trying to open user settings to unlock the user's ability to edit their user settings
When I try to open the Gnome control center with my root account I get the following error

```
root@penguin:~# XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-control-center:7565): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:54:42.877: cannot open display: 
root@penguin:~#
```

Update: after setting the display to :0 i now get

`root@penguin:~# XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused`
Solved thank you to all the people who helped

Comment: Are you at the console, or connected via SSH, e.g.? That may be the reason. If so, just as an example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549558/debian-10-cannot-open-display

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $DISPLAY`. Apparently, it is not set.

Comment: This happens when I do this with the su - command I am not sure if doing this gets me to ssh but I cant even open gnome settings with my root account

Comment: sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio the result is :0 However I can open it with my normal account but not my root when I echo $DISPLAY I get nothing `root@penguin:~# echo $DISPLAY

root@penguin:~# `

Comment: Did you sudo to your root account?  If so, you are not logged in as root so the Display= never set.  `export DISPLAY=:0` should do it.

Comment: now i get 
`No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-control-center:7630): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:57:52.102: cannot open display: :0`

Comment: I suggest you post in the question (not in comments) exactly what you are doing, when you succeed and when not, etc. Don't make people trying to help you guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out It was a problem with the host permissions execute `xhost` + to allow access from all hosts

```
aidensnyder@penguin:~$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
aidensnyder@penguin:~$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
aidensnyder@penguin:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ sudo su
# gnome-control-center
```

It would be good to clarify why do you mean to run `gnome-control-center` as root.

Comment: I get the same error